# Rpi 4b bluetooth does not show up

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth, pi-4

[image]
My bluetooth will not show up at the top right corner of the taskbar like it is supposed to. I have tried:
-Adding multiple of them in the add/remove panel items, but none show up.
-rm -r ~/.config/lxpanel and then lxpanelctl restart
-Finding the config file for the taskbar and pasting in the default code.
-updating the pi
edit: fixed the file browser.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104179/discussion-on-question-by-scratchermatch-rpi-4b-bluetooth-does-not-show-up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it in a roundabout way by installing bluez and bluetooth tools. There are still 4 bluetooth items in the taskbar, but only bluez works. I can connect with it, so I guess this is answered.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.